# GWT - paint to CanvasPixelArray with filling

Tags: gwt, canvas

I am searching (did not find yet) for a library that can paint to a CanvasPixelArray object with filling abilities.
I wan to be able to call beginFill function, draw some lines and than call endFill.

Is there such library?
Maybe GWT has such functionality?